# Google Earth Engine: Chart "User memory exceeded" shown + values keep getting rounded up to 0

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart, sentinel-5p

I use the the following code.
The first chart works properly but the second chart shows the "User limit exceeded" error

Also when I export the chart in .csv format all the values become 0.
I think its rounding off of some kind (of values very small than 0) at the backend.

What changes should I make to the code to eliminate these errors?

```
var ROI = ee.FeatureCollection("users/enigma_srl/singrauli");
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2')
  .select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2022-12-31')
  .filterBounds (ROI)
  ;
var Collection_Mean = collection.mean();

//print(Collection_Mean);


// Define a chart with one series in the forest region, averaged by DOY.
var chart1 = ui.Chart.image.doySeries( collection,ROI, ee.Reducer.mean(), 5000);
// Define a chart with a a different series for each year in the forest region

var chart2 = ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByYear( collection,'tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density', ROI, ee.Reducer.mean(), 5000);

// Display the three charts.

print(chart1, chart2);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/52506fef2ae4454b281f5c7f023c7e03